# Powering off a switching regulator causes MOSFET to briefly blip on. Arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, debounce

I have stumbled upon a weird issue in my circuit below, that only happens when the DPDT slide switch, `S1`, goes from an upwards position(On) to the downwards position(Off). The issue is that when you turn off the switching regulator, `U2`, with the switch, it occasionally will briefly blip the MOSFET `Q2` which is connected to a starter motor; the blip is so quick that the motor doesn't spin, but you can hear it. It seems to happen if you slide the switch past a certain point and speed.

After it happens once it doesn't happen again unless you turn the switch back on and repeat the sequence and hit that sweet spot where it does it again. You cannot get it to happen 100% every time but it isn't the hardest thing to try to trigger it again by playing with the switch.

In normal operation `Q1` which is a pre-biased NPN (4.7K series base resistor, 4.7K base-emitter pull-down resistor), pulls the MOSFET gate low to turn On and Off the starter motor. I already ruled out that code is not the issue by removing all code that sets `digitalWrite`.

Is this a case of contact bounce or some sort of quasi-boot/reset mode where the ATMega328P-AU pin `A1` is putting a little bit of current on `Q1`s base causing the MOSFET to briefly blip on? Some sort of weird tri-state I've never seen before.

What would be a good way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Is this schematic incomplete? You didn't connect all VCC and GND pins of the atmega. You also miss a current limiting resistor for Q1. Also I see no decoupling caps. If this is what you really got connected I'm surprised it works at all.

Comment: I omitted a few things for a smaller screenshot. Q1 doesn't really need a current limiting resistor does it? It's pulling Q2's gate low is all.

Comment: I updated the screenshot to now show everything.

Comment: The base emitter junction is pretty much a didoe. What would limit the current through it? You may blow up the gpio like that.

Comment: Did you not read my question? It's a pre-biased transistor..

Comment: Do you have the chance to measure with an oscilloscope? IMO that would help a lot to understand what the issue is. Otherwise it is just guessing. But for sure I wouldn't rule out bouncing as a reason.

Comment: @nickagian I do not have an oscilloscope yet unfortunately. What point(s) in the circuit would I measure exactly?

Comment: Well, for sure the gate and the drain of Q2 and then perhaps the base of Q1 and the EN signal of U2. All this of course while you are trying to reproduce the problem, while switching from ON to OFF.

Comment: @nickagian could I get by measuring those things with a USB type low frequency oscilloscope? I have a Fluke 117, and I can confirm with that set in MAX/MIN mode the drain of Q2 does go high briefly; definitely not VCC of BT1 because it's so quick, but enough to hear the motor click. I measured the voltage of Q1 which is so low, but since it's a BJT, I really should be measuring current between the A1 pin and the base? It's a low gain BJT (hFe about 15)

Comment: So, there is sth happening indeed... I would then measure VCC and the EN signal of U2. You should be able to see sth there as well, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @nickagian what does `sth` mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61585/discussion-between-nickagian-and-aviatorken89).

Comment: You're right, i missed it. Sorry.

Comment: I would not personally use a switch in this manner for ON/OFF control of such a regulator; a debounced transistor would be far more suitable (or a debounced input to the ATMega which then controls the ON/OFF pin). I suspect the regulator is bouncing between ON and OFF a number of times which will give all manner of interesting transients.